# Jetty9でServletをmvn jetty:runで実行する方法について

Tags: java, maven, servlet

お世話になっております。さて

[Jetty9でつくる組み込みwebサーバーとservletのTips](http://qiita.com/riversun/items/208561cfbac7c7da4898)

を参考にサーブレットを作っています。（IDEにはIntellij IDEA 2017.1.4を使っています）。リンク先にGitHubへのリンクがあり、そこからプロジェクトをダウンロードできます。IDE上で右クリック、Run  を選択するとWebサーバが起動し、サーブレットが使えます。

これをサーバで動かそうとして、`mvn jetty:run`しようとするとプラグインが足りないので、`pom.xml`に

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.4.v20170414</version>
            <configuration>
                <httpConnector>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </httpConnector>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

を追加して`mvn jetty:run`するとWebサーバは起動しますが、サーブレットが起動せず、デフォルトのディレクトリを探索できるモードになります。`mvn jetty:run`については

[MavenでJettyを動かす](http://qiita.com/moris/items/4538773013d4e17ddecc)

も参考にしています。起動時のログは

```
[INFO] Logging initialized @2971ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: jetty9-server-quick-start
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src/main/webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = /Users/keisuke/Downloads/jetty9-quick-start-master/target/classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /Users/keisuke/Downloads/jetty9-quick-start-master/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = null
[INFO] Webapp directory = /Users/keisuke/Downloads/jetty9-quick-start-master/src/main/webapp
[INFO] jetty-9.4.4.v20170414
[INFO] Scanning elapsed time=236ms
[INFO] DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[INFO] No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[INFO] Scavenging every 660000ms
[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@4078695f{/,file:///Users/keisuke/Downloads/jetty9-quick-start-master/src/main/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///Users/keisuke/Downloads/jetty9-quick-start-master/src/main/webapp/}
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@5a82ebf8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started @4135ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

となっており、`src/main/webapp`以下の静的ファイルにはアクセスできますが、サーブレットにはアクセスできません。

`main()`を含むクラスを指定することが必要だと思いますが、その方法がわかりません。

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal

を参考に手探りに設定を探していますが、解決していません。アドバイスを頂けたら幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty組み込みのWebアプリケーションをつくりたいということでしたら、これをベースにした方が早いと思います。README.mdの通りにやれば、すぐに動作確認できます。

[Example: Embedded Jetty w/ JSP Support](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp)